# iPhone unable to parse JSON results from YELP

Tags: iphone, json, touchjson

I'm attempting to parse validated JSON from a yelp search result.

This correctly spits out the json as expected (confirmed in simulator browser and my own).

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSString *dump = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    
    NSLog(@"Did Recieve data: %@",  dump);
    [JSONData appendData:data];
}
```

But when my connection finishes loading I'm having a hard time extracting the results and parsing the data:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{   
    NSLog(@"Connection Did Finish Loading");
    
    NSError *error = nil;
    id cureLocations = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:JSONData error:&error];
    [JSONData release];
        
    NSLog(@"Connection finished loading: %@", error);
}
```

I get: Connection finished loading: Error Domain=CJSONDeserializerErrorDomain Code=-11 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (CJSONDeserializerErrorDomain error -11.)"

I switched to TouchJSON from SBJSON because I wasn't able to extract it from that framework either. I've attempted loading it into Dictionaries and Arrays with null as the result. At this point I've been banging my head on the keyboard for hours and would greatly appreciate any input.

[JSON sample](http://pastie.org/1645237)

#### Update:

I am a dummy. I hadn't initialized JSONData. Please accept my apologies for wasting your time and thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: What's in JSONData at the time of `deserializeAsDictionary:error`? Can you do a dump there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, after further review of the application it seems that I rushed to copy my samples into this project and forgot to initialize JSONData:

```
self.JSONData = [[[NSMutableData alloc] init]autorelease];
```

Then I updated my didReceiveData method:

```
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [[self JSONData] appendData:data];
}
```

And everything is now working as expected. This is the second time I've run into this error. I guess I always expected the debugger to pick it up. Thanks for everyones time and assistance.

Answer (score 1):

SBJSON is a pretty decent and well known parser. If it didn't parse your input, you'd probably assume it's because the input was genuinely bad. If TouchJSON isn't parsing it either, the input is *definitely* bad. So there's something going on with you `JSONData` object that's dodgy.

I would suggest you print out your JSON data to the console in your `connectionDidFinishLoading` method and try re-validating it. See what's actually in the data object you're passing to CJSON.

Comment: Although I agree with most of what you say, http://www.jsonlint.com/ reports the JSON he links to as valid. So probably the problem is in the accumulation of JSONData — particularly as CSJSON seems to take a guess at the encoding based on the first few bytes.

Comment: I logged [JSONData length] before and after the append data call. Both points report 0, so something is wrong there.